# What makes a good engineering PhD topic and is this one?

Tags: phd, computer-science

(I don't know if this is the right place to post this, but it's the best I could think of)

I am soon to graduate from my MEng and I am contemplating doing a part time PhD in the future.

PhDs always seem very 'research' focussed, while research is certainly something I do, it has always been a secondary thing behind the doing (designing making etc.), the engineering.

How does one do a PhD where the goal is to make something? (and can one do a PhD where the goal is to make something?)

---

Now the more specific question about my current idea.

A C++/Rust like language with a *parallelism checker* that natively compiles to run segments of code on a GPU (and possibly other ASICs).

Rust's borrow checker runs anaylsis to check memory safety, a parallelism checker would run analysis to  check code is as parallel as it can be, warning when code is not and how it may be best made so (via multi-threading and/or gpgpu), even in very complex scenario. From a more mathematical perspective could a perfect algorithm/model be devised and proven that would never miss when parallelism can be implemented?

In the simplest example, giving a warning for something like:

```
int a[100000]={1,2,...,100000};
int b[100000]={1,2,...,100000};
int c[100000];
for(int i=0;i<100000;++i) {
    c[i]=a[i]+b[i]
}
```

Comment: In general, you can do a PhD that is closely tied to the needs of the industry; i.e., a research problem may come from an industry partner.  The only requirement is that the problem/widget/solution must be new with respect to the state-of-the-art.   You can start with the 'parallelism checker' idea.  Check what has been done in the literature, is it new? is there an equivalent concept, if so, then it is old.  Time for a new idea.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization_tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does one do a PhD where the goal is to make something?

### This is country specific, and needs approval from your PhD advisor.

But the lab I am working in at [CEA](http://www-list.cea.fr/) in France has several PhD candidates working on [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/). In the UK see also [this](https://web.inf.ed.ac.uk/icsa/news/mike-o-boyle-to-give-a-keynote-talk-at-cgo-2019).

You could also continue or take advantage of my work on [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (funded by [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) & [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) projects; see [this](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) *DRAFT* report). You may consider (with approval from your PhD advisor) implementing your ideas as a [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html), or as an extension of the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), or something generating [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL).

Of course, the ongoing [Brexit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit) is adding issues at end of 2020 (e.g. end of [Erasmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasmus_Programme), no more European funding to UK research labs)

> From a more mathematical perspective could a perfect algorithm/model be devised ?

Probably not a perfect one. Be however aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) and of the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Read also J.Pitrat's last book on [*Artificial Beings - the conscious of a conscious machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015), which is closely related to your topic. Also become familiar with [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) and [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) techniques. Consider [generating *C* code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065).